# How to Draw simple objects using OpenGL with a Mouse

Tags: c#, opengl, user-interface, opentk, tao-framework

I am trying to design a small application that could draw simple objects like lines,ellipses,triangles, etc... with a mouse using OpenGL. There should be a GUI which user can interact with. I thought of design the UI with C#. But I have problems getting it to work with OpenGL library since I need to get mouse interaction to this.

Most of the available codes write the code and directly produces the output to a window when the program is run.

Is there any one that could give me a tip on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

With OpenGL, all the stuff to draw are outputed each frame. So if you plan to modify coordinates of an object, you have to use variables as coordinate while calling vertex3f(x,y,z). Update the values in your mouse event handler, and next frames, new values will be used.